# The defined prefix wont load from json file discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I don't know what's the error here. If you take a look at the code down below you see I defined prefixes as prefix but it just shows the str prefix. help.

**Code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):

    with open('main code\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)


    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Color.red())

    embed.set_author(name="test")
    embed.add_field(name="testing", value=f"{prefix}")
   
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The outcome is just "prefix" Not the prefix from the json file

[image]

Comment: where did you define `prefix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line:

```
prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
```

Other way around:

```
prefix = prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)]
```

Although, prefixes is still not in scope, to solve this you can move the code into the `with` statement, for example.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):

    with open('main code\pp.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)


        prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

        embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Color.red())

        embed.set_author(name="test")
        embed.add_field(name="testing", value=f"{prefix}")
    
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```